# Completely prevent iOS web app from opening link in mobile Safari, even with links containing parameters

Tags: ios, parameters, mobile-safari, iphone-standalone-web-app

I have found multiple solutions to prevent an iOS web app from opening normal links in mobile Safari, unfortunately they do not work for links containing parameters, e.g.

```
href="index.php?s=example"
```

These are still opened in mobile Safari.

The shortest solution for normal links I have found thus far can be found [here at stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20091014/prevent-ios-web-app-w-redirect-from-opening-link-in-mobile-safari/27501667). Maybe someone can modify that script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webapp for iphone switches from home screen to Safari when url parameters are used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8476662/webapp-for-iphone-switches-from-home-screen-to-safari-when-url-parameters-are-us)

Answer (score 2):

Try 4 years old [github gist](https://gist.github.com/kylebarrow/1042026). I used it and it works.
You can use it by [`bower`](http://bower.io/):

> bower install --save iosweblinks

May be you have javascript errors on page and handlers do not call?

P.S. My modified script for prevent opening links in Safari in `standalone` mode:

```
(function (standalone) {

    if (!standalone) {
        return;
    }

    document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        var element = e.target,
            href = '';

        while (!/^(a|html)$/i.test(element.nodeName)) {
            element = element.parentNode;
        }

        if (element.getAttribute) {
            href = element.getAttribute('href');

            if ('' !== href && '#' !== href && null !== href && (!element.protocol || element.protocol !== 'tel:')) {
                e.preventDefault();
                window.location = element.href;
            }
        }
    }, false);

}(window.navigator.standalone));
```