# Prevent UIWebView Pop Out to Safari, But Still Load Page

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I'm working on an iOS application that uses a lot of `UIWebView`s. Is there are way to prevent the `UIWebView` from popping out to Safari (iFrame code) but still load the page?

In other words return `YES` in `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` but not let the web page pop out to Safari.

**EDIT:**
The web view side has processes that need to be executed, which is why I need to return `YES`. But the processes also inadvertently cause the application to launch the URL in Safari. I'm looking for a way to intercept that, and choose whether or not to launch the URL in Safari.

Comment: What does "pop out to Safari" mean? If you return `YES` the page loads, doesn't it? Isn't that what you say you want?

Comment: The web view side has processes that need to be executed, which is why I need to return `YES`. But the process also inadvertently causes the application to launch the URL in Safari. I'm looking for a way to intercept that, and choose whether or not to launch the URL in Safari.

Comment: "But the process also inadvertently causes the application to launch the URL in Safari" I've never seen that happen. Safari launches if _you_ call `openURL`. Are these your own Web pages? Why is that happening?

Comment: It is a hybrid application that relies on several views to be provided by it's mobile web counter part. They are required by the project. I can't say exactly why it's happening but the web side has requested that I handle the preventing Safari launch on my end.

Comment: Well I think they are wrong. It's their fault, they have to prevent it. See this question and answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27529966/completely-prevent-ios-web-app-from-opening-link-in-mobile-safari-even-with-lin Everything revolves around stuff internal to the web app.

Answer (score 0):

Apple introduced a Safari View Controller on iOS 9. Safari View Controller is a pre-built browser that has all the bells and whistles of Mobile Safari, but can be presented without leaving your app.

First  we need to import Safari Services

```
#import <SafariServices/SafariServices.h>
```

For Objective C:-

```
NSString *yourUrl = @"http://yourURL";
SFSafariViewController *svc= [[SFSafariViewController alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: yourUrl]];
[self presentViewController:svc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

For Swift:-

```
let svc = SFSafariViewController(URL: NSURL(string: self.urlString)!)
self.presentViewController(svc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```